# Map<ID,List<Opportunity>>

Tags: apex

I have a map as:

```
Map<ID,List<Opportuniy>> aoMap=new Map<ID,List<Opportuntity>>();
```

I will loop through the opportunity object select a few fields and I want to populate it into `List<Opportunity>` as shown above and accountID of Opportunities into the Map.assuming I loop through the opportunity how do I keep opportunity data into List and accountID of opportunity into the map.

```
Map<ID,List<Opportunity>> aoMap = new Map<ID,List<Opportunity>>();

for(Opportunity o:[
    select ID,Name,Amount 
    from Opportunity
]) { 
    if (aoMap.containsKey(o.ID)) {  
        List<Opportunity> opporList = aoMap.get(o.ID); 
    } else {
        aoMap.put(o.AccountID, new List<Opportunity> { o.ID }); 
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error when I add data to Map.

Comment: Please add the error message to your post verbatim.

Comment: It's also a lot easier to read your code when you don't run all your blocks together like that. Java formatters do an OK job of formatting most Apex.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. That's not what comments are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by looking at your code, your issue is on this line:

```
else { aoMap.put(o.AccountID,new List<Opportunity> { o.ID }); }
```

and that you are most likely getting an incorrect type error or incorrect method signature error

And that's because you are adding an *Id* in list which expects an *Opportunity*

Instead, try:

```
else { aoMap.put(o.AccountID,new List<Opportunity> {o}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about not using a map at all:

```
Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([
    SELECT Id, (
        SELECT ID, Name, Amount
        FROM Opportunities
    )
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN: accountIds
]);

for (Account a : accountMap.values()) {
    for (Opportunity o : a.Opportunities) {
        /* Do your stuff */
    }
}

// or
for (Opportunity o : accountMap.get(account.Id).Opportunities) {
    /* do your stuff */
}
```